# Supress title of listings created with the LaTeX listings package

Tags: latex, listings

I'm using LaTeX in conjunction with the listings package and I'm trying to suppress the title of a listing such that it is neither viewed below the actual listing nor in the list of listings.

Setting the option `title` to `title=""` or `title=` does not work. It only leads to the suppression of the listing in the list of listings. However, in the first case `""` is displayed below the listing and in the latter one `Listing:` is displayed below the listing.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer is under the assumption that you *do* want a caption to be displayed. Otherwise I can't see any problem in removing both the `caption` and the `title` from the optional parameters of your `lstlisting` environment.

Using the [`caption`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/) package, it is possible to control the text that comes together with your caption. For instance setting it to

```
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,labelsep=none}
```

will remove the "Listing 1:" when using a caption.

If on the other hand you don't want a listing to show in your List of listings, you can add `nolol=true` to your parameters.

I hope these suggestions can help you, please elaborate on your exact problem if they don't.

Comment: Setting nolol=true and not setting the options title or caption, respectively, does the trick. Thanks a lot.